# Django - transaction.atomic rollback after particular time

Tags: django, transactions, atomic

I am trying to create a booking app using django.

In my application the user can select a seat and make payment within 5 mins.

When a user selects a seat the state will be changed to blocked.

If payment not done within 5 mins the selected seat state should change to available.

I am not aware of how to implement that using `transaction.atomic()`.

Generally incase of an exception `rollback` can be achieved but here how do I achieve that.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    seat = Room.objects.get(account_id=location.id, seat_no=seat_no)
    seat.state = blocked
    seat.save()
```

How do I revert the status to `available` if payment not done in next 5 mins?

Comment: you have to store seat in memory and clear seat after 5 minute and you can not roll back after 5 min  as there might be other important  changes done during these 5 min

Comment: @Vaibhav Do the booking applications work the same way? Because if the internet connection is broken during process the seat is blocked till a particular duration and then made available to users.

Comment: you can write a cron job which clear all seats which blocked for >5min but not booked

Comment: You can use a scheduled task which runs after 5 minutes from the time the selection was made. You can use `celery` for this. 
However, you will need to handle the current users' selection, if the payment process takes > 5 minutes for him, directing him for doing the booking again..

Comment: What you need is a `blocked_until` field, not transactions.

Comment: @thebjorn Could you elaborate on how to use `blocked_until` field.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `blocked_until` field, i.e.:

```
class Room(models.Moddel):
    ...
    blocked_until = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(1970,1,1))
```

the default value is a "time-before-time" value, i.e. smaller than any sensible value.

Then your reserve view would do:

```
def reserve(request, roomnumber, seatno):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now5 = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

    with transaction.atomic():
        room = Room.objects.get_object_or_404(
            pk=roomnumber, seat=seatno, 
            blocked_until__lt=now                   # <== 1
        )
        room.blocked_until = now5                   # <== 2
        room.save()
```

at `1` you'll select the room/seat, but only if it isn't blocked, i.e. the block_until field value is in the past.

at `2` you block this room for five minutes.

Since you're doing two things that need to go together, you need to wrap them in a transaction.

Comment: When the user first selects an available seat `blocked_until` filed will be empty or have a lesser time than `now`, after getting the record we are updating the `blocked_until` field to next 5 mins. Then using `celery` or `cron` job I must release the seat based on payment done. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Your understanding is basically correct, although the implementation is more straight forward. Your payment processor will normally call back (web-hook) to an url on your site, once the transaction is finished, with the payment status.  Use this web-hook view to set the `blocked_until` field either to `now` (meaning the payment didn't go through and it's available again), or set `blocked_until` to value in the future (e.g. after the event is finished.)